# jQuery Mobile Creating Buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile, while amazing in many ways, tends to be frustrating at times. In this instance i am trying to dynamically create one of the very nice buttons that the library has. 
Basically what i want to do is enter text into an input field and when spacebar is pressed it creates a jQuery mobile button with the text.

My js works beautifully when im using just jquery to make the buttons etc but when i use jqm the but initialises to class=ui-btn-hidden for some reason.

Anyone with experience on jqm please help

Comment: you need to refresh the jQM controls, try adding .trigger('create') to the element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WEyyh/3/

JS

```
$('#createButton').bind('click', function() {
    $('#buttonPlaceHolder').append('<a href="#" data-role="button">'+$('#buttonText').val()+'</a>');

    // refresh jQM controls
    $('#home').trigger('create');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <input type="text" id="buttonText" placeholder="Enter Button Name"/>
        <input type="button" id="createButton" value="Create Button" />
        <div id="buttonPlaceHolder">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
</div>
```